# What's wrong with this pattern?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with this regexp

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9 -\\/_&()']*$"
```

I expect this to accept only values like `abc123/-_`'s but I'm not sure why it's even accepting `ABC`

But it's not accepting double quotes in it.

Here is my code:

```
public static final Pattern 

    PATTREN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 -\\/_&()']*$");
    Matcher m = PATTREN .matcher("ABC\"");
    return m.matches();
```

Comment: **don't use unescaped `-` at the middle of character class.** Use the hyphen at the start or at the end of char class.

Comment: Oh you got it right :) Thanks a lot @Avinash Raj. I changed my pattren to "^[a-zA-Z0-9 \\/_&()'-]*$" and its proper now. can you please brief how does the meaning differ with placement of "-" in the pattren? Thanks again.

Comment: read the second answer in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

- Only character that needs escaping within [] is the hyphen - which has special meaning. Everything else is literal, even brackets, slashes etc. which usually have meaning.
- No need for start and end markers
- You can use Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE flag in pattern rather than added extra complexity via A-Za-z 
  Code

Example

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z0-9\\-/_&()']*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("abc123/-_'s").matches());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("ABC\"").matches());
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern says, A-Z, so why do you think it would not allow uppercase characters?

You are defining a character class, using []; and anything between the square brackets is seen as "valid" character. So if you dont want uppercase letters, then remove A-Z from the [].

Btw: although it is not supporting Java, you might want to play with https://regex101.com/

That is a great site to "practice" regular expressions; and it isnt too hard to "convert" regexes from other languages to Java.

Comment: I'm okay with uppercase as its allowed and its valid too but i was specific about double quotes " which is not valid according to my reqexp.